# error handling for multiple database queries with single connection in python

Tags: python, database, error-handling

What is the best way to execute an array of queries with try catch on each query in python?

Currently i loop over all queries in the database within a try catch block to catch overall query errors. How do i convert it to a system where i can catch errors on the query level?

```py
conn = get_connection()

try:
    for query in queries:
        execute(query)
except Exception as error:
    raise(error)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

I would ideally like to use the try catch block within the for loop. However i need to use finally block to close the connection. If i place the try catch finally block in the for loop, i will have to get a new connection for each query? Any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply:

```
with get_connection() as conn:
    for query in queries:
        try:
            execute(query)
        except Exception as error:
            raise(error)
```

You should avoid Exception clause. Instead you should catch specific exceptions like `FileNotFoundError` etc.